# Form Data: wrong Content-Type for .p7m files

Tags: file, upload, mime-types, content-type, form-data

I need to save a file with correct MimeType for .p7m files (**application/pkcs7-mime**) via form upload to the server.
In the request I noticed that Content-Type is wrong:

------WebKitFormBoundaryaglEgtBJlb65v7d5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file0"; filename="getmymimeplease.p7m"
**Content-Type: application/pkcs7**

it should be:

**Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime**

How is possible that the '-mime' part is missing (or truncated) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually controlled by OS and/or Browser. On windows, this is set in the registry, in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.<fileextension>`, e.g. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.p7m`, in the Field `Content Type`:

[image: Sample for .p7m]

So in the end, this is controlled by the client. So if there are several possible mime types for the same extension, you need to cover that in your server code (accept or decline, convert to your default or not)